# Netty running at 100% CPU

Tags: java, netty

I've seen other references to this issue, such as [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1873) and [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/327), although these reference different versions of Netty. Tried this using the latest in the 4.0 branch (4.0.29) and in the 5.0 alpha branch (5.0-Alpha3). Local (non-linux) jdk 1.8.040, fine. Remote (Linux) with java jdk 1.8.025-b17 get 100% cpu.
Linux kernel version 2.6.32.

Tried using `EpollEventLoopGroup();`

Tried calling

```
workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
workerGroup.rebuildSelectors();
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions? I've seen references to this bug w/different versions of Netty. Jdk bug? Netty bug?  Process goes to 100% immediately on startup and stays there.

Update: Upgraded to java 1.8.045, same difference.

[JStack output](https://gist.github.com/stevenbenjamin/3dca326810e680a397b0) of all runnable threads (there's some rabbitmq stuff in there, only included for completeness - that's common to other applications, and is not the cause of the problem).

Comment: If you could run `top -H -p <jvm pid>` and `jstack <jvm pid>` you can see which threads consume CPU and the stacks of these threads. I also suggest running `jstat -gc <jvm pid>` to ensure that it is not a memory issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. top -H -p <jvm pid> shows 1 child proc using all the cpi. jstack shows the only things not waiting are epollWait and  java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method).

Comment: Could you post the output from both `top` and `jstack`? The enire jstack-output please but for `top` the topmost 5 threads are enough.

Comment: Link included in the question above

Comment: Did you have the top output as well, from the same run? (I want to map the top output to specific threads to identify the culprit)

Comment: DIdn't on that run, but top -H -p as you mentioned before shows 1 child thread consuming all the cpu. There's no corresponding reference to that child thread id in the stack output so I don't think it's possible to match. If you know of some other way of matching them up I could recreate.

Comment: You can match the threads by converting the pid of the process in  `top` to hexadecimal. That hexadecimal number matches the nid=0x<hexNumber> in the jstack output. That way we can identify the exact thread consuming CPU.

Comment: Thanks, never knew that. Ran the whole rigamarole again, the hex output corresponds to what reads as "pool-9-thread-1"  on line 38 of the gist, which is confusing to say the least.

Comment: Interesting. Which JVM version is the jstack output from? Do you have any own code that uses an `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` running that could cause this? Is it always the same stack for this thread (i.e. `DelayedWorkQueue.poll`?)

Comment: Your comments actually pointed me to the correct solution, so post an actual answer and I'll accept along with what turned out to be the cause of the problem, an incorrectly initialized ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As we identified in the comments, the thread that consumed CPU is busy in the following stack:

```
"pool-9-thread-1" #49 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007ffd508e8000 nid=0x3a0c runnable [0x00007ffd188b6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.poll(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have managed to reproduce a similar behavior by creating a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, configuring it to allow core threads to time out, and scheduling a lot of repeating tasks with a short delay. It yields a lot of CPU on my machine and the `jstack` output is similar (sometimes deeper into the `poll` method). This code reproduces it:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
executor.setKeepAliveTime(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
for (long i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
}
```

Now we just have to identify which code sets up a broken `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. I searched through the RabbitMQ and Netty source code without finding anything obvoius. Could it be something you do in your own code?

**Edit**: As mentioned in the comments, the root cause was a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` initialized with `0` which apparently can cause a CPU spin om some platforms. This was done in the OP's code.

Comment: Sadly, while I would like to say that someone else is at fault, it is, in fact, something to do with my own code. It turns out that if you mistakenly initialize a scheduledThreadPool with  0 you get 100% cpu spin. Why would someone do that? God only knows - certainly not something I'd ever do. 

In any case the javadocs specify using <0 throws an IllegalArgument but don't mention 0. They should probably throw the exception on 0.

Thanks for the help and enjoy the +100. I'm going to go apply for work at Burger King.

Comment: @SteveB. Glad I could help. Interesting cause!

Comment: The reason someone might do that is because they want something scheduled every 30 minutes, but not have a thread allocated for that purpose the whole time (just to wait for 30 mins to elapse) -- so you allow core threads to time out or even set core threads to 0... shame it bugs.